# AngularJS Form values not showing

Tags: angularjs

I'm a beginner at AngularJS and I am working with Bootstrap form. I set default values for my each field using below code. Why default values are not display in each field? Where have I gone wrong?

Meanwhile, how can I get form data for sending server request?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="studentController" class="container" > <br />
        <h1>Student Information:</h1>
        <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="submitStudnetForm()" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" ng-model="student.firstName" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="student.lastName" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dob" class="col-sm-3 control-label">DoB</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="date" id="dob" class="form-control" ng-model="student.DoB" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Gender</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <select id="gender" class="form-control" ng-model="student.gender">
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7"></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <span><b>Training Location</b></span>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input value="online" type="radio" name="training" ng-model="student.trainingType" />Online</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input value="onsite" type="radio" name="training" ng-model="student.trainingType" />OnSite</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <span><b>Main Subjects</b></span>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.maths" />Maths</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="student.physics" />Physics</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox"  ng-model="student.chemistry" />Chemistry</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" ng-click="resetForm()" class="btn" /> <br/>
            @* Note: This form will not be submitted in demo. *@
        </form>
        <script>
         //1. create app module 
            var studentApp = angular.module('studentApp', []);
    
            //2. create controller
            studentApp.controller("studentController", function ($scope, $http) {
      
                //3. attach originalStudent model object
                $scope.originalStudent = {
                    firstName: 'James',
                    lastName: 'Bond',
                    DoB: new Date('01/31/1980'),
                    gender: 'male',
                    trainingType: 'online',
                    maths: false,
                    physics: true,
                    chemistry: true
                };
    
                //4. copy originalStudent to student. student will be bind to a form 
                $scope.student = angular.copy($scope.originalStudent);
    
                //5. create submitStudentForm() function. This will be called when user submits the form
                $scope.submitStudnetForm = function () {
    
                    // send $http request to save student
    
                };
    
                //6. create resetForm() function. This will be called on Reset button click.  
                $scope.resetForm = function () {
                    $scope.student = angular.copy($scope.OriginalStudent);
                };
        });
        </script>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `ng-app` missing for your html :

```
<html ng-app="studentApp">
```